# Not able to access the EC2 instance added to ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have created the ECS cluster, which as of now contains only one EC2 instance.
I have deployed my node application using docker.

I tried accessing my application running on 3000 port on this EC2 instance using its public IP address. But somehow I am not getting response.

I tried to ping this IP, I get the response back. Same docker container is working fine on other instance.

Answer (score 1):

You must map the container port to your ec2 instance port. first open the port number you want to access with public address by ec2 security group

First, open ec2 instance port:

in `EC2 console > click in your instance > security groups`

Then open a port in inbound and outbound settings.

Next, map this port with your container port (3000):

`ECS > Task Definitions > your task > your container > mapping ports
Set host port: port opened, container port: 3000, protocol: tcp`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's hard to tell, but since this is probably access issue, you can try the followings.

1. Check if port `3000` is open in the `Security Group` that tied to to the ECS instance.
2. `SSH` into the EC2 instance, and check if your node app can be access via port `3000`. You need to enable the `SSH` in the `Security Group` for the EC2 for this.
3. The new ECS support dynamic port mapping, so make sure your task definition is configured to use port 3000.

That should help you narrow down where the real issue is.